# how to store the value in a variable retrieved from mysql table and to use it in another query using php

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible in `php` and `mysql` to get the value from the table using a query and store the value in a variable and use the variable in where condition of another query, for example

```
$us = mysql_query("select regional from td_user where user_id='".$_SESSION['use_i']."'");
$us_row=mysql_fetch_row($us);
$reg = $us_row[`regional`] ;
```

now i have stored the value in a variable called `$reg`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM td_excel where regional = '$reg'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
    {
    <?php echo $row['Vehicle_description'];?>
    <?php echo $row['Year'];?>
      //it will display many rows like this
}
```

its not displaying any records!!!!,am i doing it in right way..please help me!!!
P.S I am a learner!!

Comment: Why not? Did you tried it?

Comment: echo the $reg value and try to echo the $sql, see the output

Comment: Dont use `mysql_*` functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @rizer123 : ya i tried it works in mysql admin..but not in php

Comment: `WHERE regional  IN "(".implode(',',$reg).")"` But maybe try it with a JOIN if the tables are related

Comment: try `$sql = "SELECT * FROM td_excel where regional = '.$reg.'";`

Comment: @csaw : same only it shows only null results

Comment: @MarcoMura : u where right it doesn't return a value if i echo it :(

Comment: then fix your first sql code ^_^

Comment: mysql_fetch_row can be accessed with `$us_row[0]` not with its name

Comment: @Mihai : i also used the mysql_fetch_array...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM td_excel where regional = ".$reg;
```

Answer (score 0):

change `$us_row=mysql_fetch_row($us);` 
to `$us_row=mysql_fetch_array($us);`

and also change `$reg = $us_row[`regional`] ;`  to `$reg = $us_row['regional'] ;`